# What Textbox event is raised right after bound data source is updated?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

In windows forms, when I tab out of a text box, the bound data source value is updated.  I'd like to capture the events right before and right after the data source changed.  I think the OnLeave event is what I want for the before event.  In the debugger, I'm not seeing the data source value changed.  But, what event can I key off of for the after event?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an event that does exactly what you're asking, the closest I think you're going to get is to use the `DataBindings` and find your specific `Binding` and the you can catch the `Parse` event.  But I believe this event fires *before* the data is pushed back to the source, so it's not much better than the `LostFocus` event.

Answer (score 0):

The default event for TextBox DataBindings is `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation`.  When you tab out of the TextBox, the following events will fire:

- Leave
- Validating
- (data source gets updated)
- Validated

The `Validating` event has a `CancelEventArgs` parameter that allows you to cancel the leave attempt for the TextBox (the focus will remain in the TextBox).

If you use `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`, it will update the data source with every keystroke or text change.